I can't mount my external hard drive in Linux
I have a 500GB external hard drive that recently worked perfectly in Linux, but currently when trying to mount the disk it gives me this error:

Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/nomedousuario/nomedodisco: wrong fs
type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or
helper program, or other error.

Note: I use a dual boot with Windows 11 and Linux Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. And on Windows the HD works perfectly
HDD Model: ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB (2AR10002)
File system: NTFS

Welcome to AskUbuntu. When disconnecting the disk from Windows, do you “safely remove” the device? Or do you yank the USB cable out of the machine? Reason I ask is because if the NTFS file descriptor is still set to “open”, Ubuntu may not be able to access the file system. Only “safely removing” the disk will mark the partition as closed.

Any and all data devices that I connect to my PC I safely remove, both on Windows and Linux.

Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
The Windows "Fast Boot" (Windows defaults to "ON") setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

This is the correct solution. And there are several advantages by disabling fast boot if one want to dual boot into linux: your graphic card may end up in a correct state allowing linux to discover/initialize it properly (it was the only way for me to use my GeForce 3060 on my Asus laptop with "Optimus")

Sometimes one can't or forget to do a proper software disconnection of an external drive. Windows may or may not warn you about that but nevertheless it continues to work. Linux tend to be more picky about that to avoid data loss. Try to do a scan for errors (mouse right click on the drive icon -> properties -> tools -> check) under Windows. For NTFS it is just better to make Windows do the check/repair since NTFS is a Windows file system afterall...

But how could I disassemble a hdd through Windows before removing it?

Sorry, my bad. I used a technical term. With "Unmount" (corrected above) I meant just the software disconnection one usually have to do to unplug correctly any usb disk or usb key from a computer. The operation that one usually does with the icon on the lower right part of the screen of Windows.

But if you turn off Windows without safely removing it and then turn it on in Linux, could this cause the same problem?

If you reboot, it automatically do a proper disconnection of all connected drives. If you "turn off" it's tricky, since the "fast boot" of Windows (that is enabled by default) really means a sort of "pausing" Windows, not really switching it off. I suggest you to look around (=search the Internet) how to disable "fast boot" on Windows for this and other reasons.

Turn off Windows by holding the Shift key while clicking on the power off icon. This will make it easier for Linux to recognize the NTFS filesystem.

Yes holding the Shift key while clicking on the power off icon precisely turn off temporarly the "fast boot" shutdown, I just forgot this possibility, thanks for the remainder!

Are you sure your data partition is sdb1? There might be another device like a cardreader which initializes first and grabs sdb. To avoid this, look into blkid and enter that into fstab instead of sdb1.
Please check the output of fdisk -l /dev/sdb or the part in dmesg where the partitions on sdb are detected.
